# How to get product attribute 'size' value on category page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, list.phtml

How to show "size" attribute value on category page?

Answer (score 1):

Please change attribute setting in below location.

> Magento Admin > Store > Attributes > Product > Size > Store Front Properties Tab > Used in Product Listing > Yes

Comment: I have it turned on.

Answer (score 0):

add list.phtml file at your custom theme

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml
```

add below code to above template

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code');
$attributeValue = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: It is configurable product.
http://joxi.ru/KAgqJlMFg3Og6m